# Estimating LCMM() in R for traumatic brain injury patients

Tags: regression, mixed-model, latent-class

How does one specify the model in the following question:

*Are there subgroups of patients for which the trajectories of five biomarker behave similar in relation to the outcome(s) while accounting for characteristics like sex, age at injury and GCS?*

The R-package that I am using is *lcmm* and more specifically the *hlcmm()* function. However, I am puzzled in deciding what comes left and what comes right in the regression equation.

Would this be a correct specification of the model:

```
mlin <- lcmm(
  outcome ~ days + NfL + GFAP + Tau + UCH.L1 + pTau181 + Age_at_injury + Sex + GCS,
  random = ~ days + NfL + GFAP + Tau + UCH.L1 + pTau181 + GCS,
  subject = 'id',
  data = df,
  link = "linear"
)
```

And with two trajectories:

```
m2 <- hlme(
  outcome ~ days + NfL + GFAP + Tau + UCH.L1 + pTau181 + Age_at_injury + Sex + GCS,
  random = ~ days + NfL + GFAP + Tau + UCH.L1 + pTau181 + GCS,
  subject = 'id',
  data = df,
  ng = 2,
  mixture =~days + NfL + GFAP + Tau + UCH.L1 + pTau181 + GCS,
  B=m1,
)
```

Link to the method: https://cecileproust-lima.github.io/lcmm/articles/latent_class_model_with_hlme.html.

Comment: As usual with R, the dependent variable goes on the left, the independent variables go on the right. Examples of this are in the link you provided, in the sections labeled "estimate the model".  What about this is confusing you? 

The link also provides an example of estimating the trajectories.

Comment: Well, what is or are the dependent variable(s) and what are the independent variables? We observe the biomarkers over a time and have a fixed outcome measured at 24 months.

Comment: The outcome is the DV.

Comment: @PeterFlom Please see the updated question, I appreciate your help.